# print a receipt after silverlight WCF call

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight

A WCF call to DB is made to save data received from user in a silver application.

Based on business logic, the data is either saved or returns that data cannot saved.

If data is saved, a print dialog button should be opened for the user.

If data cannot be saved, a message that your data saved is not saved as such cannot print a receipt appears.

```
     testing()


        If kid = "S" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Session!!!")
        ElseIf kid = "D" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Session Expired!!")
            'Exit Sub
        ElseIf kid = "E" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Error occurred!!")
            'Exit Sub
        ElseIf kid = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Session!!")
            'Exit Sub
        Else

            If kid.Length > 4 Then
                print()
                clear()
            End If

        End If





Sub testing()
        busyIndicator.IsBusy = True
        'busyIndicator.Content = "Processing Please Wait...."
        Dim s As New services.serviceclient
        AddHandler s.confirmticketCompleted, AddressOf mcompleted


        s.confirmticketAsync(kuniqueno)

    End Sub


 Sub mcompleted(sender As System.Object, e As services.confirmticketCompletedEventArgs)
        kid = e.Result.ToUpper

        busyIndicator.IsBusy = False


    End Sub
```

What I am expecting is when a button is clicked  by user, testing() function is called. After WCF call, that is after mcompleted handler is executed, print dialog  should appear.

"kid" is being updated in WCF call and this "kid" is going to be receipt printed.

As silverlight WCF is asynchronous, WCF call and print call are asynchronous , providing irrelevant data in receipt.

I even tried putting print() function in mcompleted handler,  "print dialog should be user initiated" error appears.

Please help!!!

Print dialog should appear after WCF call updates "kid"

Answer (score 0):

You should put you checking code inside your "mcompleted" method.
Service method is executed asynchronously.

Comment: When I put checking code inside mcompleted it says "print dialog should be user initiated"